# Login PHP con BD, conexiones asincronas ajax en js

Tags: php, sql, login

Ante todo explicar que soy nuevo en este mundo y trato de aprender a base de prueba y error... para empezar, estoy creando un login contra mi base de datos utilizando conexiones asincronas con ajax donde pueda acceder a través de distintos usuarios creados mediante un registro...

mi problema ahora mismo es que no sé como asociar una contraseña a un usuario y poder acceder... escribo el código y me explico

codig php.

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($data, true);

//variable -->$id = $data['id']<-- js
$Usuario = $data['Usuario'];
$Contrasena = $data['Contrasena'];

//compruebo si existe el usuario con un contador que devuelve el numero de 
//usuarios cuyo usuario estoy introduciendo

$query = "SELECT COUNT(usuario) as contador FROM artista where usuario='$Usuario'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($connect,$query);

$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado) ;


$cc=($row['contador']);

if ($cc!="0"){
    echo " Usuario Existe ";
}

// Hasta aquí todo bien, compruebo que el usuario existe pero necesito 
//seleccionar la contraseña para ese usuario, no una contraseña de otro     
//posible usuario y poder hacer un location paraloguear y enviar al index de usuario...


$query2 = "SELECT contrasena FROM artista WHERE usuario = '$Contrasena'";

$resultado = mysqli_query($connect,$query2);

$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado) ;


$ss=($row['contador']);

if ($ss!="0"){
    echo " contrasena Existe ";
}
```

¿Podríais ayudarme?

que necesitas? saber si el usuario existe? o que necesitas en detalle, no es clara tu pregunta – Sha***

Hacer funcionar el login, si el usuario existe y su contraseña en la base de datos es la correcta para ese usuario, poder hacer una redirección y loguear con ese usuario... Me he estancado en comprobar si la contraseña es de ese usuario.

Comment: que necesitas? saber si el usuario existe? o que necesitas en detalle, no es clara tu pregunta

Comment: Hacer funcionar el login, si el usuario existe y su contraseña en la base de datos es la correcta para ese usuario, poder hacer una redirección y loguear con ese usuario... Me he estancado en comprobar si la contraseña es de ese usuario.

Comment: revisa por favor la propuesta que te hago

Answer (score 2):

Te dejo este ejemplo de MySQLi usando la interfaz **Estilo Orientado a Objetos**, para que lo adoptes a tus necesidades:

```
<?php

//Conexion a la Base de Datos (esta conexion es a modo de ejemplo)
$enlace = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pruebas");


$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$contrasena = $_POST["contrasena"];

/* crear una sentencia preparada */
$stmt = $enlace->prepare("SELECT nombre,password FROM usuario WHERE nombre = ?");

/* ligar parámetros */
$stmt->bind_param("s", $usuario);

/* ejecutar la consulta */
$stmt->execute();

/* ligar variables de resultado */
$stmt->bind_result($nombre,$password);

/* obtener valor */
$stmt->fetch();

/* verificamos que el usuario exista */
if ($nombre == $usuario) {
    /* verificamos que las contraseñas coincidan */
    if ($password == $contrasena) {
        echo "Todo Ok";
        //header('Location: principal.php');
        //exit;
    } else {
        echo "Contraseña Incorrecta";
        //header('Location login.php');
        //exit;
    }
 } else {
    echo "El usuario no existe";
    //header('Location login.php');
    //exit;
 }

?>
```

MySQLi:

Proporciona una interfaz procedural y orientada a objetos [Ver mas informacion](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php)

Espero te funcione.

Comment: no veo donde este la orientación a objetos, partiendo de que dicho paradigma emplea clases, atributos, métodos, herencia, etc

Comment: @ShadowPaz en este caso según entiendo yo a *Estilo orientado a objetos* es el estilo `mysqli_stmt mysqli::prepare ( string $query )` implementado, ya que también está el estilo por *procedimientos*
`mysqli_stmt mysqli_prepare ( mysqli $link , string $query )`, aquí el manual: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php, en su repuesta veras **MySQLi usando la interfaz Estilo Orientado a Objetos**.

Answer (score 1):

Ahora bien no se por que deseas realizar la comprobación en 2 pasos cuando pudieras hacerlo en uno solo del modo siguiente:

```
"SELECT nombre, contrasenia FROM usuario 
WHERE nombre = $usuario AND contrasenia = $contrasenia";
```

> Si la comprobación anterior arroja true significa que el usuario
>   existe y es su contraseña, entonces ya procesar para darle acceso

Pero si lo que necesitas es encontrar la contraseña específica del usuario, asumiendo que es el usuario que usas en la primer query que leo; debería bastar con:

```
"SELECT contrasenia FROM artista WHERE usuario = $Usuario";
```

¿Por qué?

> > Pues al momento de hacer la comparación necesitas validar que el
> >     nombre de usuario que ya le llegó al sistema, sea al mismo al que esta
> >     contenido en la BD y si es el mismo entonces tomar el valor de la
> >     columna contraseña
>
> Ya que a como leo tu segunda consulta cuando pones usuario =
>   $contrasenia, eso nunca va a pasar por que los 2 datos estan
>   almacenados en la misma tabla y no tienen coincidencia de ese modo

Ahora si directamente quieres saber si la consulta te devuelve si el usuario existe o no trabaja con

```
$query = mysqli_query("select * from usuarios");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
//hey existe el usuario
}else{
//no existe el usuario
}
```

> Si mysqli_num_rows es mayor a cero quiere decir que tu consulta
>   encontro una coincidencia

Comment: Esa consulta me devuelve los campos correctamente, pero como hago una validación utilizando bucles if para decir, si existe o no...? además, no me funciona la conexion asincrona al cambiar la sentencia sql del php... mmm no se :(

Comment: @DiegoRapLow prueba lo que añadí hasta el final de mi respuesta

Comment: @DiegoRapLow no tiene por que afectar a como entiendo tu ejercicio solo usas ajax para no recargar directamente la página cierto? y desde ahi procesar la petición hacia un php